# errors with ajax request and htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

i am building a small scale custom cms to handle different landing pages.

I am using .htaccess files for root and for the admin panel but i have encountered a problem in ajax requests.

For the font end the url looks like partner/page-title/country
and i redirect all requests to index using the following htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms-admin
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^skip=1$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?partner=$1&page=$2&country=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ajax.php$ /marketing/cms-admin/ajax.php [QSA]


ErrorDocument 404 /includes/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>oops..  Page not found</H1><p> If you have reached this page from an external url please visit unicaf's <a href='https://unicaf.org'> main website</a> <br> and try navigating to this page from there"


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

For the admin folder i redirect all request using :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&option=$2&action=$3 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*(.*)/*$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&option=$2&action=$3 [NC,L]
```

Now when i try for example to submit a form via ajax( lets say login), 
the POST data either fail or the request overall fails with the message:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

It does not matter what i try, even just posting "hi"in ajax.php if isset($_POST) gets me this error.

any ideas?

EDIT: 
This is a sample javascript code. i wont actually use this but i used this to experiment with ajax requests and htaccess files.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
 $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(event){

        var data = {
            "action": "test"
        };
        data = $(".js-ajax-php-json").serialize() + "&"+ 'action=test' ;
        alert(data);
        //event.target.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'ajax.php&skip=1', 
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {

                /*$(".the-return").html(
                    "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
                );*/

                //alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
                return false;
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown + ' ');
                return false;
            }
        });
        alert("loads up to here");
        return false;
    });
 });
```

it loads bu the actual requests fails with the error mentioned in the above.

**UPDATE**: 
ok it seems the problem exists mainly in chrome browser. Tried with firefox+firebug and it loaded just fine. tested by adding ana alert('success'); on success event. So the question in hand now is , why does it fail when using chrome ?

**UPDATE**: just to be sure i have tried with pure javascript to test ajax. Again it works for firefox but on chrome it throws the same typeError. This time though the request does get sent to tha ajax.php file (As i do not include it in a try catch)

```
function loadXMLDoc()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        var data="fname=Henry&lname=Ford";
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/marketing/cms-admin/includes/ajax.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: You should include the JavaScript/jQuery code you use to do the request, there seems to be an error over there.

Comment: ok, sorry bout that, i;ve updated the question.

Comment: There's an error caused on a line where you try to set/change the value of the property `data`, which I suspect to be in your `$.ajax` call. is jQuery initialized properly? Does this page also use other libraries such as Prototype which may interfer on the `$` variable? Try to locate the line where the error is caused using your browser's console and source tabs (in Chrome Inspector Tools/Firebug). Once you found the line, try to set a breakpoint on it and reproduce the error. When the code execution is paused at that line, make sure `data` is set and that `$ === jQuery` is true.

Comment: yes jquery is loaded (checked using  if (window.jQuery) then log('loaded'). 
data variable befor getting into ajax call seems to get the value correctly. The problem is on data:data, but i cant insert a breakpoint in the debugger there. i can only set in start or in end of $Ajax()

Comment: just an update it seems that the code is working with firefox but not with chrome ?